# Unable to Concat two values in Shopify LIquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to concat the variables together in shopify liquid, but I am unable to get it done

Here is my snippet

```
      {% for product in collections.brands.products %}
        {% assign productlist = product.title %}
        {{ productlist | join: ', ' }}
      {% endfor %}

      {% for product in collections.clothing.products %}
        {% assign productlists = product.title | join: ', ' %}
            {{ productlists | join: ', ' }}
      {% endfor %}

      {% assign allcombine = productlist | concat: productlists %}

      {{ allcombine }}
```

Comment: Want to combine into string format or want to create an array?

Answer (score 0):

First at all you have to concat then print it

```
{% assign productlist = product.title | append: ',' %} // concat
{{ productlist }} // print
```